# why end of recursion returns undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

just a quick question on recursion. I'm trying to make a function that displays the integers in a a range. It prints all the integers but when it gets to the end it just shows undefined.

Here's the code.

```
function range(start, end) {
    var _start = start;
    if (_start < end) {
        console.log(_start);
        range(start + 1, end);
    } else {
        console.log(_start)
    }
}
```

Comment: because `console.log()` returns `undefined`

Comment: I think that what you are trying to do is a generator function. In that case you have to return values with the keyword `yield`. You can do it is you use ES 2015.

Comment: Are you trying to run it on console?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan yes. just using the console to get the basics of the language down

Answer (score 4):

By default javascript functions return `undefined` unless you explicitly `return` something.